# Как найти ближайшую дату занятия?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть функция определения ближайшей даты указанного дня недели:

```
def next_closest(from_date, search_day, message):
print(from_date)
print(search_day)
if isinstance(search_day, str):
    search_day = WEEK_DAYS.index(search_day.lower())
from_day = from_date.weekday()
different_days = search_day - from_day if from_day < search_day else 7 - from_day + search_day
d=from_date + timedelta(days=different_days)
return next_func(d)
```

Также есть массив с предметами:

```
sub_rasp = {'0': ['История', 'биология', 'Химия', 'География', 'ИЗО', 'Технология', 'Алгебра'],
        '1': ['Обществознание', 'Русский язык', 'Информатика(Малова)', 'Информатика(Чкалова)', 'Музыка',
              'Англ.яз (Якушева)', 'Англ.яз (Васильева)', 'Физ-ра'],
        '2': ['Физика', 'Физ-ра', 'Химия', 'Литература', 'Русский язык', 'Алгебра', 'Англ.яз (Якушева)',
              'Англ.яз (Васильева)'],
        '3': ['Русский язык', 'ОБЖ', 'Биология', 'Русский язык', 'Геометрия', 'Алгебра'],
        '4': ['Литература', 'Физика', 'История', 'Алгебра', 'Англ.яз (Якушева)', 'Англ.яз (Васильева)', 'Геометрия',
              'География']}
#0 - понедельник и т.д
```

Но не правильно работает определения дня занятия:

```
    sub = n[0]
    d = date.today()
    # d = datetime.date(2020, 9, 21)
    for i in sub_rasp:
        if int(i) > int(d.weekday()):
            print(f'{i}  i > str(d.weekday())')
            for y in sub_rasp:
                print(f'\n{y}\n')
                if y == sub:
                    print(f'{y}  i > str(d.weekday())')
                    return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)], message)
    for i in sub_rasp:
        if int(i) < int(d.weekday()):
            print(f'{i}  i < str(d.weekday())')
            for y in sub_rasp[i]:
                print(f'\n{y}\n')
                if y == sub:
                    print(f'{y}  i < str(d.weekday())')
                    return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)], message)
    for i in sub_rasp:
        if int(i) == int(d.weekday()):
            print(f'{i}  i == str(d.weekday())')
            for y in sub_rasp[i]:
                print(f'\n{y}\n')
                if y == sub:
                    print(f'{y}  i == str(d.weekday())')
                    return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)], message)
   #    if str(i) > str(d.weekday()):
   #        for y in sub_rasp[i]:
   #            if y == sub:
   #                print(WEEK_DAYS[int(i)])
   #                return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)])
   #    elif i == str(d.weekday()):
   #        for y in sub_rasp[i]:
   #            if y == sub:
   #                return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)])
   #    elif i < str(d.weekday()):
   #        for y in sub_rasp[i]:
   #            if y == sub:
   #                print(WEEK_DAYS[int(i)])
   #                return next_closest(d, WEEK_DAYS[int(i)])
```

В любом из двух вариантов, возвращает понедельник(0), но должен вернуть след. день(среда, 2), при выборе предмета Алгебра

Примеры:
Если сегодня 29.09 и я выбрал Алгебра, то код должен выдать 2020-09-30.
Если сегодня 02.10 и я выбрал Историю, то код должен выдать 2020-10-05 (Понед).
Если сегодня 28.09 и я выбрал ИЗО, то код должен выдать 2020-10-5
Примеры на основании расписания (sub_rasp)

Comment: Странное сравнение `if i < str(d.weekday()):` Лучше числа в строках не сравнивать как строки, а привести к числам. А что должен тот код выдать? Просто следующий день?

Comment: В `next_closest` сломано форматирование и не хватает `return`, поправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @gil9red, код должен выдать день проведения предмета.

Comment: Пишите ник с @. Ближайший первый день? В виде номера дня недели или конкретной даты?

Comment: @gil9red, Если сегодня 29.09 и я выбрал Алгебра, то код должен выдать 2020-09-30.

Если сегодня 02.10 и я выбрал Историю, то код должен выдать 2020-10-05 (Понед).

Примеры на основании расписания (```sub_rasp```)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно, но лучше добавьте примеры в сам вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Накидал алгоритм, проверьте.

А так:

- Дни недели лучше изначально хранить как числа, а не строки, чтобы упростить дальнейшую с ними работу
- Давайте переменным понятные названия
- Думаю, лучше сразу сделать регистронезависимый поиск предмета, чтобы и `АЛГЕБРА` или `алГеБра` находили `Алгебру` среди предметов, для этого вместо условия `lesson in SCHEDULE[week_day]` используйте `lesson in map(str.lower, SCHEDULE[week_day])` и перед этим добавьте `lesson = lesson.lower()`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a7bbd36ba26faa7ade03ffc32d0b5da75a90c53d/get_nearest_lesson_date.py#L26)

```
import datetime as DT
from typing import Optional


SCHEDULE = {
    0: ['История', 'Биология', 'Химия', 'География', 'ИЗО', 'Технология', 'Алгебра'],
    1: ['Обществознание', 'Русский язык', 'Информатика(Малова)', 'Информатика(Чкалова)',
        'Музыка', 'Англ.яз (Якушева)', 'Англ.яз (Васильева)', 'Физ-ра'],
    2: ['Физика', 'Физ-ра', 'Химия', 'Литература', 'Русский язык', 'Алгебра',
        'Англ.яз (Якушева)', 'Англ.яз (Васильева)'],
    3: ['Русский язык', 'ОБЖ', 'Биология', 'Русский язык', 'Геометрия', 'Алгебра'],
    4: ['Литература', 'Физика', 'История', 'Алгебра', 'Англ.яз (Якушева)',
        'Англ.яз (Васильева)', 'Геометрия', 'География']
}


def get_nearest_lesson_date(lesson: str, d: DT.date = None) -> Optional[DT.date]:
    if not d:
        d = DT.date.today()

    # Перебор дней недели
    for i in range(7):
        next_day = d + DT.timedelta(days=i+1)
        week_day = next_day.weekday()

        # Пропуск отсутствующих дней недели, например выходных
        if week_day not in SCHEDULE:
            continue

        if lesson in SCHEDULE[week_day]:
            return next_day

    # Не нашли урок
    return
```

Проверка:

```
print(get_nearest_lesson_date('Алгебра'))
# 2020-09-30

print(get_nearest_lesson_date('Алгебра', DT.date(2020, 9, 29)))
# 2020-09-30

print(get_nearest_lesson_date('История', DT.date(2020, 10, 2)))
# 2020-10-05

print(get_nearest_lesson_date('ИЗО', DT.date(2020, 9, 26)))
# 2020-09-28

print(get_nearest_lesson_date('ИЗО', DT.date(2020, 9, 27)))
# 2020-09-28

print(get_nearest_lesson_date('ИЗО', DT.date(2020, 9, 28)))
# 2020-10-05
```

Comment: Да, это работает! Спасибо!

Comment: @12457896, пожалуйста :) кст, заметил, что для в третьем пункте `А так:` забыл добавить, что в функции нужно добавить `lesson = lesson.lower()` ([полный пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a7bbd36ba26faa7ade03ffc32d0b5da75a90c53d/get_nearest_lesson_date.py#L26))